# C cast void* data to typedef struct

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have a BST library in wich I store some structs :

```
struct bst_node {
    char *key;
    void* data;                // this one i want to get it casted to struct model
    struct bst_node* left;
    struct bst_node* right;
};
```

Here is the search function that returns me a `bst_node` that resides in bst.c:

```
struct bst_node** search(struct bst_node** root,char *key) {
    struct bst_node** node = root;
    while (*node != NULL) {
        int compare_result = compare(key, (*node)->key);
        if (compare_result < 0)
            node = &(*node)->left;
        else if (compare_result > 0)
            node = &(*node)->right;
        else
            break;
    }
    return node;
}
```

At this point I'm having in main.c this struct wich is contained in the `void*` data

```
typedef struct model_t{
    char name[MAX];
    char file_a[MAX];
    char date[MAX];
    int price;
    accesories *acs;
}model;
```

Suppose that in main.c I search for an item and get returned a tree node containing the `void*` data that I'm interested in, how can I cast that data and assign it to a model so later on I can access the fields of model (for example modify the accesories list) ?

Here are the ways I tried :

1. return the data

   ```
   model *m;
   m  = (model *)searches(root,mod);  // the searches function is similar to the search posted
   if (m != NULL) {                   //before but instead of a node returns &(*node)->data
       printf("\n--------%s\n",(*m).name);
   ```
2. return a node and assign it's data to the model *m pointer

   ```
   model* m;
   struct bst_node** node  = search(root,mod);  //return the node containing the string
                                                //in "mod" and assign node->data to m
   if (node != NULL) {  
        m=(*node)->data;
        print_list(m);             //this functions prints the accesories list
   }
   ```

I am certain there is a way to go around this but I just can't find it any help would be highly appreciated.

-----------------------------------------------------------main.c------------------------------------

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bst.h"


#define MAX 50

typedef struct accesori_t{
    char nome[MAX];
    int prezzo;
    struct accesori_t *next;    
}accesori;

typedef struct modello_t{
    char nome[MAX];
    char file_a[MAX];
    char date[MAX];
    int prezzo;
    accesori *acs;
}modello;



void stampa_lista(struct modello_t *m);
void append_node(struct accesori_t *llist,char *nome, int prezzo);
void stampa_modelli(struct bst_node* root);
void salva_lista(struct bst_node* root,char *nf);
void inserisci_modello(struct bst_node** root);
void cancella_modello(struct bst_node** root);
void inserisci_acs(struct bst_node** root);
void cancella_acs(struct bst_node** root);
//struct modello_t *cerca_modello();
void stampa_affinita(struct bst_node* root);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int menu=0;

    char nf[MAX];

    char *t;
    char nome[MAX];
    char file_a[MAX];
    char data[MAX];
    int prezzo,gg,mm,a,index=0;


    int prezzo_a;
    char nomea[MAX];
    struct accesori_t *head,*curr;
    struct accesori_t *tmp;


    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fa;
    fp=fopen("cars.txt","r+");

    struct modello_t *m;
    m = (struct modello_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct modello_t));

    struct bst_node* root=NULL;



    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d %s",nome,data,&prezzo,file_a)!=EOF){

            strcpy((*m).nome,nome);
            strcpy((*m).file_a,file_a);
            strcpy((*m).date,data);
            (*m).prezzo=prezzo;
            //printf("%s\n",(*m).nome);                  

            fa=fopen((*m).file_a,"r+");


            m->acs=(struct accesori_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct accesori_t));
            while(fscanf(fa,"%s %d",nomea,&prezzo_a)!=EOF)
            {                   
                append_node(m->acs,nomea ,prezzo_a);       
                while(m->acs->next != NULL)
                    {
                        m->acs = m->acs->next;
                        //printf("\t%s --- %d\n",m->acs->nome,m->acs->prezzo);

                    }
            }

            insert(&root, m->nome, m);   
            close(fa);

    }

    while(1){

        printf("\n\t1.Stampa Lista modelli");  
        printf("\n\t2.Inserisci nuovo modello");
        printf("\n\t3.Cancella un modello");
        printf("\n\t4.Inserisci Accesorio");
        printf("\n\t5.Cancella Accesorio");
        printf("\n\t6.Salva la lista");
        printf("\n\t7.Stampa Affinita'");
        printf("\n\t0.EXIT");
        printf("\n\t"); 
        printf("\nINSERIRE SCELTA : ");
        scanf("%d",&menu);   

        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                stampa_modelli(root);
                break;

            case 2:
                inserisci_modello(&root);
                break;
            case 3:
                cancella_modello(&root);
                break;
            case 4:
                inserisci_acs(&root);
                break;
            case 5:
                cancella_acs(&root);
                break;
            case 6:
                salva_lista(root,nf);
                break;
            case 7:
                stampa_affinita(root);
                break;
            case 0:
                return;

        }

    }  




  delete_tree(root);
  close(fp);
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

void append_node(struct accesori_t *llist,char *nome, int prezzo) {
    while(llist->next != NULL)
        llist = llist->next;

    llist->next = (struct accesori_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct accesori_t));
    llist->next->prezzo = prezzo;
    strcpy( llist->next->nome,nome);
    llist->next->next = NULL;
}

void stampa_lista(struct modello_t *m){
    while(m->acs->next != NULL)
    {
        m->acs = m->acs->next;
        printf("\t%s --- %d\n",m->acs->nome,m->acs->prezzo);

    }
}

void stampa_modelli(struct bst_node* root){
        preorder_traverse(root);
}

void inserisci_modello(struct bst_node** root){

    FILE *fa;
    struct modello_t *temp;
    char nomea[MAX];
    int prezzo_a;
    temp = (struct modello_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct modello_t));

    printf("\nInserire il nome : ");
    scanf("%s",temp->nome);

    printf("\nInserire il file degli accesori : ");
    scanf("%s",temp->file_a);

    printf("\nInserire la data di disponibilita' (gg/mm/aaaa) : ");
    scanf("%s",temp->date);

    printf("\nInserire il prezzo : ");
    scanf("%s",&temp->prezzo);


    printf("%s\n",(*temp).nome);                 
    fa=fopen(temp->file_a,"r");


            temp->acs=(struct accesori_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct accesori_t));
            while(fscanf(fa,"%s %d",nomea,&prezzo_a)!=EOF)
            {                   
                append_node(temp->acs,nomea ,prezzo_a);       
                while(temp->acs->next != NULL)
                    {
                        temp->acs = temp->acs->next;                                               
                    }
            } 
            insert(root, temp->nome, temp);   

    free(temp);
    close(fa);   
}

void cancella_modello(struct bst_node** root){

    char mod[MAX];

    printf("\nInserire il nome del modello da cancellare : ");
    scanf("%s",mod);

    struct bst_node** node = search(root,mod);

    if (*node != NULL) {
        delete(node);
    }

    preorder_traverse((*root));    
    free(node);       
}
void inserisci_acs(struct bst_node** root){
    char mod[MAX];
    char acs[MAX];
    int prezzo_a;

    //struct modello_t* m;

    printf("\nInserire il nome del modello: ");
    scanf("%s",mod);

    struct modello_t **r = searches(root,mod);

    struct modello_t *m = *r; 
    if(m != NULL) { 
        printf("\n--------%s\n",m->nome); 
    } 

    //struct modello_t *m;
    //m  = (struct modello_t *)searches(root,mod); //trovare come fare a far ritornare il void *data

    /*if (m != NULL) {
        printf("\n\nQuesto pezzo di programma e' ancora da rivedere in quanto ho dei problemi\n nel convertire void* data in struct modello\n\n" );


        //m=(*node)->data; // parte problematica
        //stampa_lista(m);
        printf("\n--------%s\n",(*m).file_a);
        printf("\nInserire il nome dell'accesorio da aggiungere: ");
        scanf("%s",acs);
        printf("\nInserire il prezzo dell'accesorio da aggiungere: ");
        scanf("%s",prezzo_a);

        while(m->acs->next != NULL)
        {
            m->acs = m->acs->next; 
            if(m->acs->next == NULL)
                append_node(m->acs,acs ,prezzo_a);                                                   
        }

    }*/
    free(m);    

}
void cancella_acs(struct bst_node** root){
    char mod[MAX];
    char acs[MAX];


    //struct modello_t *m;

    printf("\nInserire il nome del modello: ");
    scanf("%s",mod);

    struct bst_node **node  = search(root,mod);

    if(*node == NULL) 
    { 
        puts("Not found"); 
    } else { 
        struct modello_t *m = (*node)->data; 

    if(m == NULL) 
    { 
        puts("Found, but data is NULL"); 
    } else { 
        printf("\n--------%s\n",m->nome); 
    } 
    }

    /*if (node != NULL) {
        printf("\nQuesto pezzo di programma e' ancora da rivedere in quanto\n ho dei problemi nel convertire void* data in struct modello\n" );


    m=(struct modello_t*)((*node)->data); // parte problematica

     printf("\n--------%s\n",m->prezzo);
    //stampa_lista(m);

    printf("\nInserire il nome dell'accesorio da cancellare: ");
    scanf("%s",acs);


         while(m->acs->next != NULL)
        {   
            if(strcmp(m->acs->next->nome, acs)){
                if(m->acs->next->next==NULL)
                   m->acs->next==NULL;        
                m->acs->next=m->acs->next->next;
                break; 
            } 
            m->acs = m->acs->next; 

        }
    }*/
    free(node);   
}

void salva_lista(struct bst_node* root,char *nf){
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fa;
    fp=fopen(nf,"w+");
    char na[MAX];

    struct modello_t *m;
    //m = (struct modello_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct modello_t));

    /*while(ritorna_nodi(root)) 
    {       m=ritorna_nodi(root)

            fprintf(fp,"%s %s %d %s",(*m).nome,(*m).date,(*m).prezzo,(*m).file_a);                              
            fa=fopen((*m).file_a,"w+"); 

            while(m->acs->next!=NULL)
            {                   
                fprintf(fp,"%s %d ",m->acs->nome,m->acs->prezzo);
                m->acs=m->acs->next;
            }
            close(fa);               
    }*/
    close(fp);  
}
stampa_affinita(struct bst_node* root)
{
      stm_aff(root);   
}
```

---------------------------------------------------bst.c---------------------------------------------

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bst.h"
#include "data.h"


struct bst_node* new_node(char *key,void* data) 
{
    struct bst_node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct bst_node));
    assert(result);
    result->data = data;
    result->key=malloc(strlen(key)*(sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(result->key,key);
    result->left = result->right = NULL;
    return result;
}

int compare(void* left,void* right)
{
    if (strcmp(left,right)<0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(left,right)==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}



void free_node(struct bst_node* node) 
{
    assert(node);
    free(node);
    node = NULL;
}

struct bst_node** search(struct bst_node** root,char *key) {
    struct bst_node** node = root;
    while (*node != NULL) {
        int compare_result = compare(key, (*node)->key);
        if (compare_result < 0)
            node = &(*node)->left;
        else if (compare_result > 0)
            node = &(*node)->right;
        else
            break;
    }
    return node;
}

void* searches(struct bst_node** root,char *key) {
    struct bst_node** node = root;
    while (*node != NULL) {
        int compare_result = compare(key, (*node)->key);
        if (compare_result < 0)
            node = &(*node)->left;
        else if (compare_result > 0)
            node = &(*node)->right;
        else
            break;
    }
    return (*node)->data;
}

void insert(struct bst_node** root,char *key, void* data) {
    struct bst_node** node = search(root,key);
    if (*node == NULL) {
        *node = new_node(key,data);
    }
}

void delete(struct bst_node** node) {
    struct bst_node* old_node = *node;
    if ((*node)->left == NULL) {
        *node = (*node)->right;
        free_node(old_node);
    } else if ((*node)->right == NULL) {
        *node = (*node)->left;
        free_node(old_node);
    } else {
        struct bst_node** pred = &(*node)->left;
    while ((*pred)->right != NULL) {
        pred = &(*pred)->right;
    }
    /* Swap values */
    void* temp = (*pred)->key;
    void* temp1 = (*pred)->data;

    (*pred)->data = (*node)->data;
    (*pred)->key = (*node)->key;

    (*node)->data = temp;
    (*node)->key = temp1;

    delete(pred);
    }
}

void visit(struct bst_node* node)
{
    printf("%s\n", node->key);
}

void preorder_traverse(struct bst_node* root)
{
    if (!root) return;

    visit(root);
    preorder_traverse(root->left);
    preorder_traverse(root->right);
}

void inorder_traverse(struct bst_node* root)
{
    if (!root) return;

    inorder_traverse(root->left);
    visit(root);
    inorder_traverse(root->right);
}

void postorder_traverse(struct bst_node* root)
{
        if (!root) return;

        postorder_traverse(root->left);
        postorder_traverse(root->right);
        visit(root);
}

void delete_tree(struct bst_node* root)
{
    if (!root) return;

    delete_tree(root->left);
    delete_tree(root->right);

    free_node(root);
}
void*  ritorna_nodi(struct bst_node* root){

    if (!root) return;

    ritorna_nodi(root->left);    
    return root->data;  
    ritorna_nodi(root->right);      
}
void stm_aff(struct bst_node* root) // visita preorder quindi per ogni nodo visitato stampa la sua lista
{
    if (!root) return;

    //stm_vst(root);
    stm_aff(root->left);
    stm_aff(root->right);
}
/*void stm_vst(struct bst_node* root) // dovrebbe ritornare una lista di accesori di quel nodo
{
   return; 
}*/
```

-----------------------------------------------------------bst.h-------------------------------------

```
#ifndef _BST_H_

struct bst_node {
    char *key;
    void* data;
    struct bst_node* left;
    struct bst_node* right;
};

struct bst_node* new_node(char *key,void* data);

void free_node(struct bst_node* node);
typedef int my_comparator(void* left, void* right);



struct bst_node** search(struct bst_node** root,char *key);
void insert(struct bst_node** root,char *key, void* data);
void delete(struct bst_node** node);
void preorder_traverse(struct bst_node* root);
void inorder_traverse(struct bst_node* root);
void postorder_traverse(struct bst_node* root);
void delete_tree(struct bst_node* root);

#endif
```

So the pieces I'm having trouble with are the commented ones in main.c, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Get out of needing to cast a void pointer? Seriously?

Comment: `(model *)searches(root,mod);` is plain wrong, you are casting `struct bst_node**` to `model *`. In second method, maybe you need `if (node != NULL && (*node)!= NULL)`. What problem are you facing with method 2?

Comment: @another.anon.coward searches is different from search thus it returns (*node)->data

Comment: @another.anon.coward on method 2 I'm having problems assigning the data to m and then accesing the m fields

Comment: Terribly sorry! Epic failure of vision :| ... Probably something going wrong while adding... since quite some time has passed hopefully you have fixed your problem or you have some pointers

Comment: well I haven't managed to correct it and now it's on hold until a teacher of mine haves a look over the code and gives me some feedback about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do this:

```
struct bst_node **r = search(root,mod);
if(*r == NULL) {

  puts("Not found");

} else {

  model_t *m = (*r)->data;
  if(m == NULL) {
     puts("Found, but data is NULL");
  } else {
     printf("\n--------%s\n",m->name);
  }

}
```

If that does not work(please explain in detail how things "doesn't work"), there is something else wrong.

You could also change the search() function to just return a bst_node* , having to deal with a double pointer seems unneccessary here

Comment: It prints me another name (always the same name) if I try to access other attributes like price it crashes

Comment: Then perhaps there's something wrong somewhere else. e.g. memory corruption ? some error where you build up the BST ?

Comment: I can add/delete nodes without error so I suppose the erroe is when I cast the data or smth.

Comment: @Lucian Enache no its not, not if you tried the above code. Maybe you're not allocating memory properly for the structs. Maybe you're inserting nodes declared on the stack, maybe the insertion code is wrong, or something else.

Comment: well the node inserted might be declared on the stack because it's declared as temp node inside the search function then returned therefore is a temporary node, any ideea on how to fix this ? maybe use a global temp node or pass on search a pointer and then return it ?

Comment: @Lucian Enache You better show that code. The code within the search function is fine.

Comment: I've posted all the code, the commented code in main.c is the one giving me issues, look at functions inserisci_acs() and 
cancella_acs() wich would have to add/delete an item in the linked list accesori *acs of the struct modello

Comment: @Lucian Enache You're only allocating 1 struct modello_t , and you're inserting the same modello_t over and over again, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `search` function returns `struct bst_node**` which can't be casted to `struct model_t*`. Return type of this function should be `struct model_t*` and you should `return (*node)->data;` I guess.

Also note that there is no reason to pass `struct bst_node**` to this function. Pass `struct bst_node*` instead. If `root` is declared as `struct bst_node**` then call your function like this: `search(*root, mod);`, but I don't see any reason for it to be double pointer, so change its declaration to `struct bst_node* root;` so that you call your function by simple `search(root, mod);`.

Comment: but this would mean to modify the external librayro of the bst container  modify all it's functions and so on

Comment: @LucianEnache: I haven't noticed that it's in external library. Check my answer now.

Comment: @LucianEnache If the external library is obscure, it should be changed as well. As it is, the code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: it's a double pointer because I use that function for deleting nodes also... as I said this should be a library to handle generic types

Comment: I'm using 2 types of search function (one returns a node while another one returns node->data) but without any drop of success

Comment: @LucianEnache: Well, in the body of function that you have provided you don't modify first argument. It could be declared as `const struct bst_node* root`.

Comment: @LucianEnache Don't use the same function for two different purposes. Use different functions. It appears that the complexity is already too hard to handle. Famous quote by Kernighan: `“Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.”`

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout just saying

```
m = (struct model_t*)((*node)->data);
```